# How to install Mysql package for python on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I am new to python. I am using Visual Studio + python tool to develop python. I am trying to learn how to install the mysql package/library as I need to develop code to interact with the mydql db server.

Answer (score 0):

For Python and mySQL on visual Studio you need to work with Python 2.7 and download the mySQL connector from this  [Link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5)
 after installation you should be able to use import MySQLdb